# Working with dictionary of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

What I want the code below to achieve is that for which ever dictionary who has smaller value of temporary key, add an item in that dictionary with key "permanent" and value same as the value for the temporary key.

```
Variable="a"
a_list={'a': {'c': '2', 'b': '1'}, 'c': {'a': '2', 'b': '3'}, 'b': {'a': '1', 'c': '3'}}
a_list[Variable]["permanent"]="1"
for item in a_list[Variable].keys():
    try:
        if a_list[Variable][item]!=0:
            a_list[item]["temporary"]=a_list[Variable][item]
    except KeyError:
        pass
for item in a_list.keys():
    if "permanent" in a_list[item].keys():
        del a_list[item]

print a_list
```

the output now is

```
{'c': {'a': '2', 'b': '3', 'temporary': '2'}, 'b': {'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'temporary': '1'}}
```

But after adding an statement I want the output to be

```
{'c': {'a': '2', 'b': '3', 'temporary': '2'}, 'b': {'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'temporary': '1', 'permanent': '1'}}
```

I don't know how to achieve this by comparing the two temporary keys in the two dictionaries.
Would very much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The `min` function will iterate over a list. If given a special `key=` named parameter, it will use the one-argument function passed in as the `key=` function to extract the value to use for comparison purposes.

You show dictionaries using only strings containing digits. The maximum string is therefore 'A' (asciibetically later than a digit). So:

```
max_value = 'A'
min_temp = min(a_list.keys(), key= lambda k: a_list[k].get('temporary', max_value))
```

At this point, `min_temp` has the first key in `a_list` that has the lowest value for sub-dict key 'temporary', or if none had that subkey, the first key returned by `keys()` (with a defaulted value of `max_value`). So let's double-check that it was a valid match:

```
if 'temporary' in a_list[min_temp]:
    a_list[min_temp]['permanent'] = a_list[min_temp]['permanent']
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the help! But how do I implement it to my code to make it produce the output that I want it to?

Comment: Print the variable `a_list` afterwards?

Comment: The output didn't change at all...idk why. There is no "permanent" key generated